# What are these markings on the A380 wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, airbus-a380

There are some "markings" over the wings and the horizontal stabilizer. Could somebody explain what they are?

[image: a380]

Comment: Note, these markings are not restricted to the A380. Almost all commercial aircraft in similar shape have these markings on their flight control surfaces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The darker areas denote where it is safe to step. Stepping outside of these areas could cause damage to the aircraft.

Here's a closeup of the warning:
[image: Quantas Flight 32 Wing]

(This happens to be a photo of [Qantas Flight 32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32) after its un-contained engine failure)

Comment: Why walking is required on the wing?

Comment: New bottom-tier Ryanair ticket. In all seriousness, maintenance personnel are the most likely people to have to heed this warning.

Comment: So the warning is printed both ways so it can be read by those already walking outside the allowed area?

Comment: .. or someone on a step ladder, about to step onto the area